# Javascript callbacks in Typescript. Accessing both class members and javascript 'this' parameter

Tags: typescript, highcharts, angular2-highcharts

I am using an Angular wrapper for a library called HighCharts. There is a callback for when I hover over the chart which is a javascript callback. The `this` parameter of this javascript function provides me with data that I need but I also would like to access my typescript class variables using the typescript `this` keyboard.

```
const options: Highcharts.Options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: null
  },
  tooltip: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      style: {
          padding: 0
      },
      useHTML: true,
      formatter: function() {
          return '<div style="float:left">' +
        '<small>Hour ' + this.point.x + '</small>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div style="float:left;">Production: <b>' + this.point.y + '%</b></div>' +
        '<div style="float:left;">Yield: <b>' + this.yieldCurrent + '%</b></div>' +
        '<div style="float:left;">Reject: <b>' + this.rejectCurrent + ' pcs.</b></div>' +
        '<div style="float:left;">Uptime: <b>' + this.uptimeCurrent + '%</b></div>';
      }
   }
}
```

If I use the `funtion() {}` I can access the `this` provided by highcharts.

If I use the fat arrow `() =>` I can access the `this` provided by my class.

How Can I access both of these parameters inside the callback? I need to access `this.point` from highcharts and `this.yieldCurrent`, `this.rejectCurrent`, `this.uptimeCurrent` from my class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can save the component reference in the chart object and then use it inside `tooltip.formatter` function.

Save component reference in component constructor:

```
  constructor() {
    const self = this;

    self.chartCallback = chart => {
      self.chart = chart;
      chart.chartComponent = self;
    };
  }
```

Use it in the `tooltip.formatter`:

```
tooltip: {
  formatter: function() {
    const chart = this.series.chart,
      chartComponent = chart.chartComponent;

    return this.y + " - " + chartComponent.yourProperty;
  }
}
```

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/vmvylr0v2y

Answer (score 0):

You could reference the `this` object of your class to some variable and then use it inside the `formatter` funciton.

Initialize a const somewhere on the top or in the constructor like this

```
const self = this;
```

Then use it wherever you want it, inside the code where this object has changed.

```
const options: Highcharts.Options = {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  title: {
    text: null
  },
  tooltip: {
      borderWidth: 0,
      style: {
          padding: 0
      },
      useHTML: true,
      formatter: function() {
          return '<div style="float:left">' +
        '<small>Hour ' + this.point.x + '</small>' +
        '</div>' +
        '<div style="float:left;">Production: <b>' + this.point.y + '%</b></div>' +
        '<div style="float:left;">Yield: <b>' + self.yieldCurrent + '%</b></div>' +
        '<div style="float:left;">Reject: <b>' + self.rejectCurrent + ' pcs.</b></div>' +
        '<div style="float:left;">Uptime: <b>' + self.uptimeCurrent + '%</b></div>';
      }
   }
}
```

Hope this helps